# Troubleshooting Dual-Boot Startup Issues: Windows 11 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a dual-boot setup with Windows 11 and Ubuntu on the same SSD. However, I'm facing an issue where Windows 11 always starts by default, even though I've been attempting to change the boot order to prioritize Ubuntu. Despite my efforts to modify BIOS settings and set a timer for the boot options, my laptop continues to start Windows 11 automatically without presenting the boot menu. As a result, I have to manually intervene to start Ubuntu. I'm seeking guidance on how to rectify this situation, regain control over the boot order, and ensure that the OS selection menu appears during startup, allowing me to choose between Windows 11 and Ubuntu seamlessly.

Comment: What model is your computer?  Different vendors sometimes do non-UEFI modifications to their boot up code.  Sometimes the bootloader name needs to be changed, sometimes you can get around vendor modifications by putting the device first in the bootorder, thereby using the default bootloader EFI/boot/bootx64.efi (which should be a copy of shimx64.efi or grubx64.efi)